# Motivated by Level Sets, how can I show that minimizing this functional is equivalent to this PDE?

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, optimization

I would like to show, that minimizing the functional 
$$F(g)=\alpha\int_\Omega |\nabla g(x)|^2dx+\mu \int_\Omega (g(x)-f(x))^2dx $$
is equivalent to solving the differential euqation
$$-\alpha\nabla g(x)+\mu g(x)=\mu f(x),\qquad x\in\Omega$$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \nu}g(x)=0,\qquad x\in\partial\Omega$$
wheren $\Omega=[0,1]^2$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial \nu}g(x)$ is the normal derivative of $g$. I started by computing the first variation of $F$ and found
$$\frac{d}{d \varepsilon}F(g+\varepsilon\bar{g})|_{\varepsilon=0}=\int_\Omega 2\alpha \nabla g\nabla \bar{g}+2\mu g\bar{g}\ dx-2\mu\int_{\Omega}f\bar{g}\ dx \overset{!}{=}0$$
Is this correct so far? How can I apply Green's identities here to find the differetnial equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be a typo in the equation, since $\nabla g\in \Bbb R^n$, and $f,g\in\Bbb R$, so dimensionally the equation does not make sense. It should be
$$-\alpha\Delta g+\mu g=\mu f.$$ The boundary condition depends on which space you want to minimize the functional over, lets assume it is $V=\{v\in H^1(\Omega):\frac{\partial v}{\partial\nu}=0\}$, this space is affine, so the problem makes sense (Mazur's lemma states that a closed and convex set is weakly closed). You have found that for all $\overline{g}\in V$, 
$$\int_\Omega 2\alpha\nabla g\cdot\nabla\overline{g}+2\mu g\overline{g}-2\mu f\overline{g}\,dx=0.$$
Noting that $\overline{g}\in V$, the divergence theorem tells us that $$\int_\Omega 2\alpha\nabla g\cdot\nabla\overline{g}\,dx=-2\alpha\int_\Omega\overline{g}\Delta g\,dx,$$
so we have 
$$\int_\Omega (-2\alpha\Delta g+2\mu g-2\mu f)\overline{g}\,dx=0\quad\forall\overline{g}\in V.$$
The fundamental lemma of the calculus of variations tells us that the integrand must be zero (at least in a distributional sense) and so we have the PDE.

Comment: yes! sorry for the typo. This is exactly the step I was missing, thanks!